# Retry ajax request after timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using a prefilter to redo the ajax request 2 times max, see code below.

However the problem is that the original fail() handler of the ajax request is also called. This needs to be disabled of course.

```
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    // retry not set or less than 2 : retry not requested
    if (!originalOptions.retryMax || !originalOptions.retryMax >= 2) {
        return;
    }
    // no timeout was setup
    if (!originalOptions.timeout > 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (originalOptions.retryCount) {
        originalOptions.retryCount++;
    } else {
        originalOptions.retryCount = 1;
        // save the original error callback for later
        if (originalOptions.error) {
            originalOptions._error = originalOptions.error;
        }
    };

    // overwrite *current request* error callback
    options.error = $.noop();

    // setup our own deferred object to also support promises that are only invoked
    // once all of the retry attempts have been exhausted
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    jqXHR.done(dfd.resolve);

    // if the request fails, do something else yet still resolve
    jqXHR.fail(function() {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

        if (originalOptions.retryCount >= originalOptions.retryMax || jqXHR.statusText !== "timeout") {
            // add our _error callback to our promise object
            if (originalOptions._error) {
                dfd.fail(originalOptions._error);
            }
            dfd.rejectWith(jqXHR, args);
        } else {
            $.ajax(originalOptions).then(dfd.resolve, dfd.reject);
        }
    });
});
```

My request is: And i get the console.log message "we are in fail" at the same time as the request is redone for the first time. Any idea how to fix this?

```
        $.ajax({
        url: url,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        type: type,
        timeout: 20000,
        async: (async === undefined ? true : async),
        beforeSend: beforeSend,
        retryMax: (type == "POST" ? 0 : 2),
        data: data
    }).done(function(response, status, xhr) {
            }).fail(function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("WE ARE IN FAIL");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easier way (sorry I only have the time to write partial code) :(

Create a recursive function that handle the ajax request and takes parameters + a counter.

```
var MyFuncAjax = function(params, counter){
  if(counter <= 0){ return true; }

  $ajax({
    ...
    timeout: params.timeout
    ...
  })
  ...fail(function(xhr...){
    MyFuncAjax(params, --counter)
  })
}
```

Then call it

```
MyFuncAjax({timeout: 20000, ....}, 2)
```

And voila :)